# converting varchar to binary in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data in a table like so:

```
create table tutor(
   id int,
   accessto varchar(8)
);
```

The data looks like this:

```
+-------+----------+
| id    | accessto |
+-------+----------+
|    69 | b'1011'  |
|   162 | b'1011'  |
|   232 | b'1011'  |
|   257 | b'0010'  |
|   258 | b'1011'  |
|   258 | b'1011'  |
|   258 | b'1011'  |
|   258 | b'1011'  |
|   258 | b'1011'  |
|   258 | b'1011'  |
|   258 | b'1110'  |
|   258 | b'1001'  |
|   258 | b'0011'  |
|   258 | b'1001'  |
+-------+----------+
```

I want to convert this into binary. How is it possible?

I tried these queries but getting the same result:

```
select id, cast(accessto as BINARY) from tutor;
select id, convert(accessto,binary) from tutor;
```

How to do this?

**My expected result is should be like this:**

```
 +-------+----------+
    | id    | accessto |
    +-------+----------+
    |    69 | 11  |
    |   162 | 11  |
    |   232 | 11  |
    |   257 | 2  |
    |   258 | 11  |
    |   258 | 11  |
    |   258 | 11  |
    |   258 | 11  |
    |   258 | 11  |
    |   258 | 11  |
    |   258 | 14  |
    |   258 | 9  |
    |   258 | 3  |
    |   258 | 9  |
    +-------+----------+
```

Comment: What's your expect result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the accepted answer is unnecessarily complex, here a concise answer:

### TLDR;

The result can be achieved in one step:

```sql
SELECT CONV(TRIM("'" FROM SUBSTRING("0b'1011'", 3)), 2, 16);
```

### Explanation

Starting point is a string containing `0b1011`:

```sql
SET @string = "0b'1011'"; -- (string) 0b'1011'
```

We can apply *string* operations to get it closer to a number:

```sql
SET @plainnumber = TRIM("'" FROM SUBSTRING(@string, 3)); -- (string) 1011
```

We can then convert the string into a real number, without sign because there is none: (You cannot use *binary* as a type here, because it is a [string type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-types.html). This step is optional because MySQL will cast implicitly.)

```sql
SET @number = CAST(@plainnumber AS UNSIGNED); -- (unsigned) 1011
```

You can now do whatever you want with it. The OP wanted to get the decimal representation which can be acquired with CONV:

```sql
SELECT CONV(@number, 2, 10);
```

### Explanation for hexadecimal

If your starting point is a string containing a hexadecimal representation:

```sql
SET @string = "41"; -- 0x41
```

You can use the UNHEX function to get a binary string:

```sql
SELECT UNHEX(@string);
```

Or you can use CONV to get a numerical representation:

```sql
SELECT CONV(@string, 16, 10); -- decimal (65)
SELECT CONV(@string, 16, 2); -- binary (0100 0001)
```

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55418020/3340665) if you are converting UUIDs

Comment: There should be some sort of bonus for excavating and providing a solution to such an old question..

Comment: @P.Salmon Actually, there is: https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer?userid=3340665

Answer (score 1):

You may have to do this the 'hard' way and create a bit field either in tutor or another table, internal conversion seems to work better than cast and convert

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(
   id int,
   accessto varchar(8),
   abit bit(8)
);


insert into t(id,accessto) values
(    69 , b'1011') , 
(   162 , b'1011') , 
(   232 , b'1011') , 
(   257 , b'0010') , 
(   258 , b'1011')  ,
(   258 , b'1011') , 
(   258 , b'1011') , 
(   258 , b'1011') , 
(   258 , b'1011') , 
(   258 , b'1011') , 
(   258 , b'1110') , 
(   258 , b'1001') , 
(   258 , b'0011') , 
(   258 , b'1001') ;

update t
set abit = accessto;

    MariaDB [sandbox]> select bin(abit),cast(abit  as unsigned) from t;
+-----------+-------------------------+
| bin(abit) | cast(abit  as unsigned) |
+-----------+-------------------------+
| 1011      |                      11 |
| 1011      |                      11 |
| 1011      |                      11 |
| 10        |                       2 |
| 1011      |                      11 |
| 1011      |                      11 |
| 1011      |                      11 |
| 1011      |                      11 |
| 1011      |                      11 |
| 1011      |                      11 |
| 1110      |                      14 |
| 1001      |                       9 |
| 11        |                       3 |
| 1001      |                       9 |
+-----------+-------------------------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: yes absolutely. Since `"b'1011'"` is already in bit notation for insertion. Thanks.

Comment: This can be done without an additional table, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66453964/3340665).

Answer (score -1):

You should using CONV mysql function

```
select id, CONV(BINARY(accessto), 2, 10) from tutor;
```

Answer (score -1):

-- Replace 'binary' with 'UNSIGNED'

```
select id, cast(accessto as UNSIGNED) from tutor;
```

Comment: All converted to 0 :(