# How to convert MySQL's BIGINT into unsigned without losing data?

Tags: mysql, type-conversion, bigint

I need to convert MySQL database tables column from (signed) `BIGINT` into unsigned `BIGINT`. If I do:

```
ALTER TABLE `$tblNm` MODIFY `flgs` BIGINT UNSIGNED;
```

Any values that have 63-bit set are reset to 0!

What do I need to do so that all values are converted without any loss?

Comment: hey, someone didn't like the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55417627/mysql-convert-char32-datatype-to-binary16-without-losing-data)

You can also try to add new column with **unsigned BIGINT**

```
         ALTER TABLE `$tblNm`
         ADD COLUMN new_column BIGINT UNSIGNED AFTER flgs;
```

Then update casted values in new column by using **cast**

```
        UPDATE `$tblNm` 
        SET new_column=CAST(flgs AS UNSIGNED);
```

Then drop column **flgs**

```
       ALTER TABLE `$tblNm`
       DROP COLUMN flgs;
```

Rename the new column with **flgs**

```
       ALTER TABLE `$tblNm`
       CHANGE COLUMN new_column flgs BIGINT UNSIGNED
```

**EDIT**
In order to execute this in transactions we can update this as following.

```
         SET autocommit=0;
         START TRANSACTION;
         ALTER TABLE `$tblNm`
         ADD COLUMN new_column BIGINT UNSIGNED AFTER flgs;
         UPDATE `$tblNm` 
         SET new_column=CAST(flgs AS UNSIGNED);
         ALTER TABLE `$tblNm`
         DROP COLUMN flgs;
         ALTER TABLE `$tblNm`
         CHANGE COLUMN new_column flgs BIGINT UNSIGNED;
         COMMIT;
```

**EDIT-2**
If there is need to lock tables before starting transactions, the above script will be changed as

```
         SET autocommit=0;
         LOCK TABLES `$tblNm` WRITE
         ALTER TABLE `$tblNm`
         ADD COLUMN new_column BIGINT UNSIGNED AFTER flgs;
         UPDATE `$tblNm` 
         SET new_column=CAST(flgs AS UNSIGNED);
         ALTER TABLE `$tblNm`
         DROP COLUMN flgs;
         ALTER TABLE `$tblNm`
         CHANGE COLUMN new_column flgs BIGINT UNSIGNED;
         COMMIT;
         UNLOCK TABLES;
```

In this case, you dont need to explicitly write `START TRANSACTION`

Comment: Your `INSERT INTO` statement has an error (it probably must be an `UPDATE`), but otherwise I like the idea. This seams like a big overkill, but there doesn't seem to be any other way without losing data.

Comment: And the cast must be `CAST(flgs AS UNSIGNED)` and not what you have in there. Then there must be `DROP COLUMN` followed by `CHANGE COLUMN`. So why don't you adjust all that and I'll mark it as an answer -- unless someone else has a better idea?

Comment: I didn't specify the version of MySQL, so maybe your syntax works on newer versions. I'm on `5.7.25` and there the cast must be `CAST(flgs AS UNSIGNED)` and renaming `ALTER TABLE tbl CHANGE new_column flgs BIGINT UNSIGNED`.

Comment: And this probably needs a transaction (or whatever they call it in MySQL.) `SET autocommit=0;` and then wrap it in `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`

Comment: IDK, do we need to lock the table or is it automatically locked after a `BEGIN`? This stuff -- `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 0,18446744073709551615 FOR UPDATE;`

Comment: If there is need, then you can LOCK [table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html)

Comment: Very good. Now it looks like it may work. Thanks. So much effort though just to do a simple `MODIFY`.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE` will commit any open transaction. See: [Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand - You have a bitmask stored as BIGINT (signed) and the column contains negative numbers (leftmost bit set to 1). You want to convert the column type to BIGINT UNSIGNED preserving the binary value.

I would suggest to convert the type to `BINARY(8)` and then to `BIGINT UNSIGNED`. Unfortunately the second step didn't work. But converting over `BIT(64)` works in my test. So you can try:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY `flgs` BIT(64);
ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY `flgs` BIGINT UNSIGNED;
```

Test case:

```
create table tbl (flgs bigint);
insert into tbl (flgs) values (1), (-1);

ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY `flgs` BIT(64);
ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY `flgs` BIGINT UNSIGNED;

select * from tbl;
```

Returns:

```
| flgs                 |
| -------------------- |
| 1                    |
| 18446744073709551615 |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nFhRs8oQHwtibkgFbVM87n/0)

Comment: yeah, thanks. That might be a better solution. At this point though I have already converted all my data using the method that I marked. So if someone else runs into the same issue, they may try your method.